# How to copy 12GB file from Ubuntu 19.10 to Android if My RAM size is 8GB

Tags: files, android, rsync, dd, cp

I tried different options to copy a 12GB movie from Ubuntu to Android (connected as a Camera for reliable connection, with mtp situation even worse), but surprisingly for me there is a RAM+SWAP shortage problem (totally 16GB minus used part) the problem is displayed on the picture:
[RAM+SWAP filled 99.9%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AMmB.png).
Copying process continues, Ubuntu hangs for a minute and after that error appears (or not).

Tried to copy with:

- Files app
- DC app (shows Stream error)
- cp, rsync, dd

All doesn't work for me, same result - memory filled, copying stops.

Any ideas how to simply copy big file with Ubuntu?

Comment: How patient were you?  The copy may be VERY slow, see launchpad bugs 1208993,1677370,1267648

Comment: Sams Note 9, USB Type-C + USB3.0, so copying speed is really fast (100-200MB/s)

Comment: didnt ```flag=direct``` work on ```dd```

Comment: Can't remember name of flags i used, but I used some, possibly direct. Also tried nocache with rsync, but same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ You just have to split your file with the following command:

```
zip --split-size 1g zipfilename name_of_your_movie
```

This will split your file to multiple zipped parts of 1Gb each, that you can move one by one.

2/ Then re-assemble the parts with the following command:

```
zip --split-size 0 zipfilename.zip --out unsplitted
```

This will create a unified zip file named unsplitted (this would be ironic if the movie your moving is "Split" :P )

3/ Unzip the unsplitted.zip file: `unzip unsplitted.zip`, and voila!

Comment: Since the OP asked to get the file into his Android device, will _zip --split-size 0 zipfilename.zip --out unsplitted_ work there?

Comment: Not from the phone. From Ubuntu, as the phone is accessible as a folder.

Comment: OP wrote: "copy a 12GB movie from Ubuntu to Android ..." so he would need to reassemble the file in the Android device.

Comment: Yes. The drawback is that he has to have twice the size (so 24 Gb), as the compressed files and the final uncompressed movie will be stored in the phone.

Comment: except for my options 2, 3, and 4.

Comment: I splitted with ```zip --split-size 3g zip_filename.zip name_of_movie``` and reassembled file on android with 7zipper (unzipping was faster than zipping).

Answer (score 1):

1) Split the file into two pieces using [7Zip](https://itsfoss.com/use-7zip-ubuntu-linux/) [(man page)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/7z.1.html) - split the file with no compression for best speed. Copy over each piece to Android, then with [zArchiver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.zdevs.zarchiver) or [7zipper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.joa.zipperplus7v2) installed on the Android, join the files back together into your humongously sized movie.

OR

2) Downsize the movie file with the Open Source app [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) or equivalent, to a size which does not fail. Copy the smaller file.

OR

3) Reencode the movie using [HEVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding) (aka H.265) with Handbrake or equivalent to downsize the file, if your Android device plays HEVC well. I use VLC on my OnePlus 7Pro and HEVC works like a champ. Your mileage may vary.

OR

4) Bypass the direct connection between the PC and the Android device and transfer it via WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `split` and `cat`:

```
split --size=1G movie.mp4 movie.mp4.split
```

copy the files, and in a terminal emulator on Android:

```
cat movie.mp4.split* >> movie.mp4
```

Like the zip method, this requires double the amount of space. If your file is very large and there is not enough space on the target, you can incrementally concatinate each part and remove it afterwards:

```
for part in movie.mp4.split*; do
    cat "$part" >> movie.mp4
    rm "$part"
done
```

Now we can automate this process. The following `sh` script does

- split the specified file in parts of the specified size
- put all files in a directory
- generate a `sh` script to reassemble the parts

For example, calling

```
sh split.sh movie.mp4 100M
```

creates a folder `movie.mp4.split` with parts of size 100MB and a script `unsplit.sh`. That script reassembles `movie.mp4` in the same directory as `movie.mp4.split` and deletes itself and the folder afterwards.

**split.sh:**

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
    echo "Please specify the file to split"
    exit 1
fi
if [ ! -f "$1" ] ; then
    echo "File not found: " $1
    exit 2
fi

size=1M

if [ ! -z "$2" ] ; then
    size=$2
fi

filename=$(basename "$1")

dirname="$1".split
mkdir "$dirname"

split --bytes="$size" "$1" "$dirname/part"



unsplit_script="$dirname/unsplit.sh"

cat > "$unsplit_script" <<EOF

#!/bin/sh

working_dir=\$(dirname "\$0")

if [ -f "\$working_dir/../$filename" ] ; then
    echo "File already exists: $filename"
    exit 1
fi

for part in "\$working_dir"/part*; do
    cat "\$part" >> "\$working_dir/../$filename"
    rm "\$part"
done

rm "\$0"
rmdir "\$working_dir/../$dirname"

EOF
chmod +x "$unsplit_script"

exit 0
```

Comment: Not a simple solution, but I like it. Should work fast and effective. Will try as soon as I get back to my pc.